# Sqoop job in Oozie cannot run Hive import

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, oozie

I've got a problem with running sqoop job in Oozie using Hue. I have 4 nodes cluster based on Hortonworks HDP.

My Sqoop job looks like below:

```
import 
--options-file ./dss_conn_parms.txt 
--table BD.BD_TABLE
--target-dir /user/user_1/DMS
--m 1 
--hive-import 
--hive-table BD.BD_TABLE_HIVE
```

The data from Oracle database was succesfully downloaded and inserted to HDFS. Unfortunately, Hive import doesn't work. The error is associated with permission:

```
73167 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - Loading uploaded data into Hive
2016-10-17 09:42:55,203 INFO  [main] hive.HiveImport (HiveImport.java:importTable(195)) - Loading uploaded data into Hive
73180 [main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool  - Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "hive": error=13, Permission denied
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:528)
at org.apache.sqoop.util.Executor.exec(Executor.java:76)
at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeExternalHiveScript(HiveImport.java:391)
at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeScript(HiveImport.java:344)
at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:245)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:514)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:148)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:184)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:226)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:235)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:244)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.runSqoopJob(SqoopMain.java:197)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.run(SqoopMain.java:177)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:47)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.main(SqoopMain.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:241)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1709)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
... 31 more

2016-10-17 09:42:55,216 ERROR [main] tool.ImportTool (ImportTool.java:run(613)) - Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "hive": error=13, Permission denied
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:528)
at org.apache.sqoop.util.Executor.exec(Executor.java:76)
at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeExternalHiveScript(HiveImport.java:391)
at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeScript(HiveImport.java:344)
at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:245)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:514)
at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:148)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:184)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:226)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:235)
at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:244)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.runSqoopJob(SqoopMain.java:197)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.run(SqoopMain.java:177)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:47)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.main(SqoopMain.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:241)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1709)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
... 31 more

Intercepting System.exit(1)

<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]
```

Do you have any idea why Sqoop job cannot run Hive import command?

**UPDATE**

I executed Sqoop job with hive import options in command line and I know what is the problem. In command line I can see this info:

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258 /hive/lib/hive-common-1.2.1000.2.4.2.0-jar!/hive-log4j.properties
OK
```

The problem is with access to hive-common-1.2.1000.2.4.2.0-jar which is located on local file system. Any idea what should I do?

Comment: Permission denied in logs , please check for your access to create hive import

Comment: I have acces to create hive import, because I am able to run this sqoop command from command line. I think the problem is Oozie or Hue.

Comment: can you post the core-site.xml

Comment: @NirmalRam This is my core-site.xml file. http://pastebin.com/sjug1SnY

Comment: @MateuszGrabowski have you tried this https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/28068/when-using-hive-import-through-sqoop-sometimes-i-g.html

Comment: @NirmalRam I updated my answer. Do you know what I can do?

Comment: I dont think this is the issue, bce if you run as cli, it will take lib from local path.
Whereas when running as oozie sqoop action lib will be from share/lib/ hdfs path

Comment: Did you copy the hive-site.xml to HDFS ? Or you can import the table to hdfs path using --target-dir and set the location of hive table to point that path, that would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try Adding

```
<env-var>HADOOP_USER_NAME=YOUR_USERNAME</env-var>
```

within the `<shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.2">` section of your job definition in workflow.xml

2) In core-site.xml add

```
   <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
   <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
   <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.YOUR_USERNAME.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
   <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.YOUR_USERNAME.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
```

and restart all services, then try again